# How can I detect visual blocks in a PDF?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ocr

I'm trying to OCR resumes. My first problem is, before OCR, to get the main blocks of a document.

Since all the resumes have "visual blocks" (referring to professional experience, skills, languages, hobbies, whatever ...), I wonder if there's any open source solution to "split" into "blocks" a document, obviously no matter the layout design (that's where some kind of AI will work, I assume)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First decompress your pdf using zlib.
you will then be able to see the pdf in a readable format - https://web.archive.org/web/20141010035745/http://gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF#A_first_example

The pdf format is kind of similar to postscript.

also try converting your pdf to postscript to see how contents are arranged.

you can decompress the pdf using pdf-parser https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/10/30/pdf-parserpy/

try this as well - https://gist.github.com/averagesecurityguy/ba8d9ed3c59c1deffbd1390dafa5a3c2

Once you can see how your data is presented => you can then start applying alogorithms to extract more meaning.